# IE11 resubmitting request instead of following redirect (Caching issue?)

Tags: internet-explorer, redirect

Seeing inconsistent behaviour in IE11 (firefox, chrome and safari all work as expected) when dealing with multiple redirects both across and within the same domain.  Specifically, when a user attempts to access our main app (landing app for suite of webapps), there is a series of redirects that happen to authenticate the user and return to that app with a one time use ticket that can be validated.  This happens successfully followed by one final redirect to instruct the browser to navigate to the original target URL for which it now has an authenticated HTTP session.  Intermittently, IE11 is not following this redirect but instead resubmitting the request containing the one-time-use ticket.  This fails as the ticket can only be validated once.

Fiddler capture overview linked below (1 + 1 geo-redundant configuration where blue is standby host and red is primary host).  ROOT(/), session-manager and cas are all separate apps running in tomcat:
[Fiddler Request Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifAWd.png)

**-----Unexplained Behaviour-----**

**Request/Response 813** Final request made to original target app containing the one-time-use ticket.  This ticket is successfully validated on the backend (can tell by the logs) and a redirect is issued to the original target URL.  In this case "/".

```
GET https://<primary>/login/cas?ticket=ST-392-40GUmY6GPkPC5QDPSCSF-lteperdrix HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 135.117.210.203
Cookie: XXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1

HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://<primary>/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:14 GMT
```

**Request/Response 814** Instead of following the redirect as expected, IE resubmits the same request.  This fails with a 401 as validation of the ticket on the backend fails.  It should be noted that you are successfully authenticated at this point and if you manually visit the target URL of the redirection that it works correctly.

```
GET https://<standby>/login/cas?ticket=ST-392-40GUmY6GPkPC5QDPSCSF-lteperdrix HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: 135.117.210.203
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE


HTTP/1.1 401
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: fr-FR
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:14 GMT
Content-Length: 1242
```

**-----Full Request Breakdown-----**

Full output at the bottom of this question.
Most of this flow is generic Spring Security and CAS functionality.

**Request/Response 802** - Login request to our authentication server (CAS) on the standby host (contains authentication artifact from third party SSO solution).  This is redirected to primary host untouched.

**Request/Response 804** - Primary authentication server accepts request and validates authentication artifact then redirects to the supplied service URL

**Request/Response 805** - Navigate to target URL provided by third party client with one time use ticket.  Happens to be on standby so it redirects to primary untouched.

**Request/Response 806** - Login URL on primary ignores the ticket and since browser is already logged in it redirects to the default landing URL which is "/".

**Request/Response 807 through 812** - Spring Security Filters on ROOT app intercept request, cache target URL and send browser through the standard redirection flow for CAS/Spring Security.

**Request/Response 813** - Browser redirected to Spring Security URL on ROOT app with one time use authentication ticket.  Ticket is validated on the backed and browser is put through final redirect to the original target URL from Request 807.

**Request/Response 814** - Instead of following redirect, IE11 resubmits the request.

**-----Other Notes-----**

- Only reproducible if initially accessing the standby host and getting a 307 redirect to the primary.
- Redirect flow from Request 805 to 813 happens if accessing primary host directly but never fails in that case.
- Clearing cache and closing/opening browser makes it succeed on next attempt.  Only seen on second attempt or later.
- Intermittent.  Does not consistently occur on second login sequence.

I'm really thinking this is some sort of redirect caching problem but I can't see what is causing it.  Shouldn't the no-cache, no-store cache-control headers tell the browser to not cache anything?

**-----Raw Fiddler Capture-----**

```
Request 802

GET https://<standby>/cas/login?service=https://<standby>/cas/login&client_name=XXXXClient&SAMLart=AAITGdXkYEZ%2F18QZblpXoKqlW28zhGh0dHBzOi8vc3Rhci5jYS5hbGNhdGVsLWx1Y2VudC5jb206ODQ0My90ZXN0L1NhbmVTaW11L3NhbmVSZXNvbHZlQXJ0aWZhY3Q%3D HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <standby>
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 307
Location: https://<primary>:443/cas/login?service=https://<standby>/cas/login&client_name=XXXXClient&SAMLart=AAITGdXkYEZ%2F18QZblpXoKqlW28zhGh0dHBzOi8vc3Rhci5jYS5hbGNhdGVsLWx1Y2VudC5jb206ODQ0My90ZXN0L1NhbmVTaW11L3NhbmVSZXNvbHZlQXJ0aWZhY3Q%3D
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:10 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 804

GET https://<primary>/cas/login?service=https://<standby>/cas/login&client_name=XXXXClient&SAMLart=AAITGdXkYEZ%2F18QZblpXoKqlW28zhGh0dHBzOi8vc3Rhci5jYS5hbGNhdGVsLWx1Y2VudC5jb206ODQ0My90ZXN0L1NhbmVTaW11L3NhbmVSZXNvbHZlQXJ0aWZhY3Q%3D HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=FEAEBFFEEA85FC3745F921DD0CDC31B2
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: <primary>


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires:
X-Application-Context: cas:native:8443
Set-Cookie: TGC=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.Qpz34BWit8XpdYEcxMlavPDiNfGx8ZlAQcTSmDpCKsylSxPk6tltnKIf86acVXIyVcOlZJyHS3ERjSjTAWDebw; Expires=Wed, 27-Mar-2019 13:52:12 GMT; Path=/cas/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: https://<standby>/cas/login?ticket=ST-54-pf2lZTUIgZ1imzsXwZgtGrrVUbec1OJziQc
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:12 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 805

GET https://<standby>/cas/login?ticket=ST-54-pf2lZTUIgZ1imzsXwZgtGrrVUbec1OJziQc HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: <standby>
DNT: 1


HTTP/1.1 307
Location: https://<primary>:443/cas/login?ticket=ST-54-pf2lZTUIgZ1imzsXwZgtGrrVUbec1OJziQc
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:12 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 806

GET https://<primary>/cas/login?ticket=ST-54-pf2lZTUIgZ1imzsXwZgtGrrVUbec1OJziQc HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: TGC=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.Qpz34BWit8XpdYEcxMlavPDiNfGx8ZlAQcTSmDpCKsylSxPk6tltnKIf86acVXIyVcOlZJyHS3ERjSjTAWDebw; XXXX_JSESSIONID=FEAEBFFEEA85FC3745F921DD0CDC31B2


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires:
X-Application-Context: cas:native:8443
Location: /
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:12 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 807

GET https://<primary>/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=FEAEBFFEEA85FC3745F921DD0CDC31B2
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
Set-Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE; Expires=Thu, 26-Apr-2018 13:52:12 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://<primary>:443/session-manager/login?service=http

s%3A%2F%2F<primary>%2Flogin%2Fcas
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:12 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 808

GET https://<primary>/session-manager/login?service=https%3A%2F%2F<primary>%2Flogin%2Fcas HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Set-Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE; Expires=Thu, 26-Apr-2018 13:52:13 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://<primary>/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2F<primary>%2Fsession-manager%2Flogin%2Fcas
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:12 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 809

GET https://<primary>/cas/login?service=https%3A%2F%2F<primary>%2Fsession-manager%2Flogin%2Fcas HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: TGC=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.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.Qpz34BWit8XpdYEcxMlavPDiNfGx8ZlAQcTSmDpCKsylSxPk6tltnKIf86acVXIyVcOlZJyHS3ERjSjTAWDebw; XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires:
X-Application-Context: cas:native:8443
Set-Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE; Expires=Thu, 26-Apr-2018 13:52:13 GMT; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Location: https://<primary>/session-manager/login/cas?ticket=ST-391-Z15wIU4u6vkgsAjcPxz0-lteperdrix
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:13 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 810

GET https://<primary>/session-manager/login/cas?ticket=ST-391-Z15wIU4u6vkgsAjcPxz0-lteperdrix HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://<primary>/session-manager/login?service=https%3A%2F%2F<primary>%2Flogin%2Fcas
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:13 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 811

GET https://<primary>/session-manager/login?service=https%3A%2F%2F<primary>%2Flogin%2Fcas HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: private
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Set-Cookie: ssoid=4537493b5e104f9d9ea341a9d374996c; Secure; HttpOnly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://<primary>/cas/login?service=https://<primary>/login/cas
Content-Language: fr-FR
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:13 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 812

GET https://<primary>/cas/login?service=https://<primary>/login/cas HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: TGC=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.WlhsS2FHSkhZMmxQYVVwcllWaEphVXhEU214aWJVMXBUMmxLUWsxVVNUUlJNRXBFVEZWb1ZFMXFWVEpKYmpBdUxsQnhTVU41TjJvM1NuSkxWMVJmWTNWUGNUYzVXVkV1TXpkRlJsOHhjMTh4T1dWQlJIaDBVRmwyZDNOTU5XMUdlVTFLUVU5MmEyUndaMnBXUlhWeFVGUTRRbXA0Wm10eFkybFJlREJJWmpsaE1tRnZRWEJ1VTNaMmRqaFpaMmgyVTNGdFJsOWlXVWx6T0ZkUlRYZzFlV053UkdZMFYxcERWVlJWY2tGRlEyZFVValJ3YlhaMloyOXlOek51ZGpVemEzbGtVbUprYzNRNFR5MDVOSFU1YVVocmIwSTJjbmxCU0hCRWMyMXdNakpEY3pWWFdqZzJTVTVvVDJzME5TMVhjVVpKUld0RVFVeExYemt4TWxsTVZGcHdVMGQzT0ZaeWVrdFBTV3BQWkRoSWVtazNlbXRIZEhCSGExVklRUzVUWWxJdFIyZEpia0pUTTBOMWRrUnpURll4UzFsQg.Qpz34BWit8XpdYEcxMlavPDiNfGx8ZlAQcTSmDpCKsylSxPk6tltnKIf86acVXIyVcOlZJyHS3ERjSjTAWDebw; XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-store
Expires:
X-Application-Context: cas:native:8443
Location: https://<primary>/login/cas?ticket=ST-392-40GUmY6GPkPC5QDPSCSF-lteperdrix
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:13 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 813

GET https://<primary>/login/cas?ticket=ST-392-40GUmY6GPkPC5QDPSCSF-lteperdrix HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE
Connection: Keep-Alive
DNT: 1


HTTP/1.1 302
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Location: https://<primary>/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:14 GMT



------------------------------------------------------------------
Request 814

GET https://<primary>/login/cas?ticket=ST-392-40GUmY6GPkPC5QDPSCSF-lteperdrix HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: fr-FR
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: <primary>
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cookie: XXXX_JSESSIONID=13EF4B22BF22A3B80F799DEDEE9527CE


HTTP/1.1 401
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Language: fr-FR
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 13:52:14 GMT
Content-Length: 1242

<!DOCTYPE html>
.
.
.
</html>
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem with IT (11.0.49) where instead of following a redirection, it continuously reload the page ... Did you find an explanation/solution?

Comment: No, I have yet to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: JFYI: after having installing all Microsoft Updates, IE has been updated to version 11.0.60. With 11.0.60, we don't have the problem anymore.